# Application Dispose call prevent

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, azure

I have ASP.NET MVC application, which is hosted on Azure CLoud Service.

I'm using CQRS architecture with command handlers.

And this system always has running threads, which are constantly working in background. The main goal of application is SMS sending for medical center patients. System works with following steps:

1. System start command (for example StartMessageSending) which
   selects some patients
2. It sends SMS notifications to them
3. And goes to sleep on definite time interval.

After interval timeout this thread repeats all previous steps until exists any patients for sending.

Parallel to this, system can runs any number of another threads with same command (StartMessageSending). On the average system has about 3 simultaneously running threads with StartMessageSending command.

If I look at the application logs, I see frequent calls of Application Dispose.
And these dispose lead to strange behaviour of system: commands don't finish their work.

I give 2 examples of logs:

1) **Correct** work of command

[image]

2) **Incorrect** work of command

[image]

And after it application calls dispose on several occasions.
And interval disposes equals of 30 seconds.
[image]

After these App Disposes currently working command **don't finish** its work.

I want to note, that I disable idleTimeout (20 minutes of unusing) timeout on IIS and set to specific night time periodicRestart IIS recycle.

Also application is very huge and this problem occures very often in working of different commands. I give an example with general description of problem.

So may be anybody knows:

***1) How I can to prevent these Application Disposes?***

***2) Or what are the possible reasons of their calls? (in general)***

Thanks :)

Comment: While these screenshots are lovely, we need to see your code

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, Application is very huge and this problem occures very often in working of different commands. I give an example with general description of problem.

Comment: General description isn't enough. We can only assume what's being done wrong and can't give me than a general answer. Please try making a simple, small but complete reproduce of your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideal fix would be to move the message sending logic to a worker role and use a queue to send the command to the worker role.

But as a quick fix, you can continuously 'Ping' your application from itself so that it won't get shutdown (not that frequent), this article describes how to do it.

http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2007/May/10/Forcing-an-ASPNET-Application-to-stay-alive